# Always loopback into loginscreen: How do I fix it? (Ubuntu 18.04, gdm3)

Tags: 18.04, login, ubuntu-gnome, gdm, display-manager

Installed a fresh 18.04 on a Lenovo T440. After 2 days, Ubuntu presents me a loopback into login screen every time I try to login.

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>STRG</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> brings me into console, where I can proceed with login and startx brings me into a blank desktop environment, where some stuff is missing (this is unity-like taskbar thing for example).

Tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`. Nothing.

`service gdm3 restart` just gets me back into loginscreen, where the problem persists.

How can I fix this? Is this known as a bug of some kind? Is there a failsafe display manager for older hardware on 18.04?

I would be ok with using another dm if there is no other way to fix this. I just need something stable. Used unity (16.04) and / or mate environment (mint) till now. First time with gdm3..

Edit: Output of gdm.service (logged in with "gnome" after installing "gnome" as dm - see answer below)

```
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-03-04 10:07:29 CET; 13min ago
  Process: 1009 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1011 (gdm3)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4291)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
           └─1011 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Mär 04 10:07:29 x-ThinkPad-T440 systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
Mär 04 10:07:29 x-ThinkPad-T440 systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Mär 04 10:07:29 x-ThinkPad-T440 gdm-launch-environment][1023]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Mär 04 10:07:37 x-ThinkPad-T440 gdm-password][1349]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_gnome_keyring.so): /lib/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffn
Mär 04 10:07:37 x-ThinkPad-T440 gdm-password][1349]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_gnome_keyring.so
Mär 04 10:07:39 x-ThinkPad-T440 gdm-password][1349]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user x by (uid=0)
Mär 04 10:07:44 x-ThinkPad-T440 gdm-launch-environment][1876]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Mär 04 10:10:14 x-ThinkPad-T440 gdm-password][2042]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_gnome_keyring.so): /lib/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffn
Mär 04 10:10:14 x-ThinkPad-T440 gdm-password][2042]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_gnome_keyring.so
Mär 04 10:10:23 x-ThinkPad-T440 gdm-password][2042]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user x by (uid=0)
```

Comment: Tried                                                                                                                                                    ```sudo apt purge gdm3
 sudo reboot
 sudo apt install gdm3
 sudo service gdm start```, which gave me output ```creating config file.../greeter.dconf-defaults with new version gdm.service is not active, cannot reload. invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "reload" failed.```

Comment: remove gdm3 and install lightdm or try `sudo systemctl start gdm3` then `systemctl status gdm3`

Comment: Did what you proposed. Output as edit in original question, after I am logged in via gnome (installed ```ubuntu-gnome-desktop``` before).

Answer (score 2):

It could happen because of:

- Drivers have been screwed up
- User config files have been screwed up
- Ubuntu desktop config files or packages have been screwed up
- Newer kernel has a bug or doesn't support some drivers modules
- Some hardware issue exists

To eliminate the issue you could try:

- Drivers reinstalling
- Create new user and check if it works
- Purging ubuntu-desktop using `sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt purge *-gnome-*`
- Loading from older kernel or install older kernel and boot with it
- Try to replace graphics card if it is possible and check with it

If you use Intel graphics drivers, it claims:

> As the only industry-certified fully open source graphics driver,
>   Intel's graphics drivers are already integrated into all popular Linux
>   distributions, which means you’ll get the latest advancements without
>   ever needing to install a separate driver. We develop this driver in
>   collaboration with a community of developers around the industry based
>   on standard specifications from the Khronos Industry Consortium*. Our
>   operating system (OS) partners seamlessly integrate the driver into
>   their OS in a way that every system with Intel graphics can display
>   every detail, every shadow, and every animation in vivid 3D.

Comment: I give feedback on your comments and use semicolon as ways to cut the answers. I don't know which drivers that could be; I might try that, thanks; I purged that now, don't know what it did though; Might do that aswell; not possible.

Comment: actually, videodrivers usually is the cause. But in your case it works with different DE. So drivers are not the cause of problems as I could see.

Comment: ```x@z-ThinkPad-T440:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] Passwort für y: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff ```

Comment: I'll try to find a more suitable driver, if I can connect the problem to the i915, which is apparently the current driver. Thanks

Comment: What is a DE? :)

Comment: desktop environment: lubuntu-desktop, budgie-desktop, xubuntu-desktop and so on

Answer (score 1):

Did this: sudo apt install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, now I can login with gnome. Meh workaround.